# Copying data to another task

Tags: c++, vxworks

I have two tasks. I want to copy the data from one to another. I cannot think of any way to do this without using `new` which I try to avoid. Is there any way to do this? For reference I am on vxWorks.

If I have some basic object

```
class Module {
   public:  
     char data[1024];
};
```

and two objects that live in different stacks

`Module a`

and

`Module b`

How can I copy data from one to the other?

If I were to do

`memcpy(a.data, b.data, 1024);`

This would still occur in the context of one of those tasks (probably A in this case). I could do `new` and then assign the ptr, but then that data is just on the heap somewhere and could leak. But I also cannot think of any other possibility.

Comment: What do you mean by Task?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743123/task-in-vxworks

Comment: @terratermatwoa Create a [mcve] and include the VxWorks version you are using.

Comment: A couple of decades ago, the vxWorks I worked with provided more than one kind of inter task messaging.

Comment: Well, use new and make it not leak. It's not like leaks occur spontaneously.

Comment: The safest way is to use msgQSend.

Comment: Try using IPC like pipe or message queue to send data to task.